# setOnSeekBarChanged in XML or another way to listen to seekBar events in seperate activity?

Tags: java, android, xml

The project I have includes a main activity that displays a dialog with a listview that uses an adapter to add each element from an XML file. This includes a seekBar. I want to be able to listen to seekBar events in the activity. For the checkboxes in the listView I was able to add the listener directly in the XML and then just implement it in the activity, but I haven't found a way to do this for the seekBar.

The other obvious option would be set the onSeekBarChanged listener, passing it the activity in the Adapter code and extend onSeekBarChangedListener in the activity. The problem is I can't figure out how to pass the activity to the adapter.

Here's the XML for the list view items

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="placeholderText"
    android:onClick = "layerChecked" />

<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBarOpacity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:max="1000" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to this the second way. I implemented the listener in the activity, grabbed the context from the constructor of the array adapter, stored it in a private class variable and then set the context (cast as a listener) as the seekBarListener.

```
private Context activity;

public LayersAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Layer> layers){
    super(context, R.layout.item_layout, layers);
    activity = context;
}
```

and then

```
opacityBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener((OnSeekBarChangeListener) activity);
```